# How to store this list view?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have 2 activites updating an list view (one is adding item and one removing item and displaying the list) I want to store the list(named schedule) even after app closes and resume from my list when app reopens.

Activity which add items on to List named Schedule

```
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(final AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(CloudEvents.this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Save Event")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to save this event into your schedule?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            Toast.makeText(CloudEvents.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            String itemAtPosition = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(CloudEvents.this, MySchedule.class);
                            MySchedule.schedule.add(itemAtPosition);
                            startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Activity which contains the list view and has delete option upon long press

```
public class MySchedule extends AppCompatActivity {

static ArrayList<String> schedule = new ArrayList<>() ;
ListView scheduleListView;
ArrayAdapter myArrayAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_schedule);
    setTitle("Schedule");
    scheduleListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.scheduleListView);
    myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, schedule);

    scheduleListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
    scheduleListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MySchedule.this)
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                    .setTitle("Are you sure ?")
                    .setMessage("Do you want to delete this note")
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            schedule.remove(position);
                            Toast.makeText(MySchedule.this,"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            myArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                    .show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

I tried using shared preferences in onPause and onResume Method but it didnt worked properly and didnt update list beyond 2 items.I did this

```
  @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.yatin.whatshappeningdtu", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();

    String json = gson.toJson(schedule);

    editor.putString("Key", json);
    editor.commit();
}
 @Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.yatin.whatshappeningdtu", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("Key", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
    schedule = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Kimdly suggest a method to save my list.Thank You !

Comment: first of all, i don't recommend using SharedPreferences for large data (it's a key-value) storage, second, you can save to storage directly when you add item, from first activity, then in second activity just read the content and populate the list, when you delete iten (in second activity) update storage file with new list.  for now .. can you log `json` value after each line of those: `String json = sharedPreferences.getString("Key", null);` and `String json = gson.toJson(schedule);` and see is the data correct in both logs ?

Comment: Just did and only empty strings are printed on logs and app crashes whenever i delete a item. how do i go on storing directly ?

Comment: you need to debug your code and see what is going on, store directly i mean, instead of `MySchedule.schedule.add(itemAtPosition);` get data from storage, add the item, and save it back. then in the other activity read data and fill the list, also when you remove item, you need to update stored data.

Answer (score 0):

While you reload `this.schedule` the adapter `this.myArrayAdapter` still uses the old content. Try to reload the adapter

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.yatin.whatshappeningdtu", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = sharedPreferences.getString("Key", null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        schedule = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        myArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, schedule);
        scheduleListView.setAdapter(myArrayAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Didnt work.It reduced to storing one item for the list

Answer (score 0):

If you are just going to use String objects you can save the list items separated by  comma

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < schedule.size(); i++) {
   sb.append(schedule.get(i)).append(",");
}
editor.putString("Key", sb.toString());
```

then you just need to get the String and split it:

```
String[] scheduleArray=  sharedPreferences.getString("Key", "").split(",");
schedule = Arrays.asList(scheduleArray);
```

Comment: Didnt Work,It stored only one item for the list